# How to add setTimeout to this code for 1 minute?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js, settimeout

how could i add a 1 minute timeout to this code before it answers?

```js
//cd test
    client.on("message", (msg) => {
        if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${PREFIX}1cd`)) {
let user = message.mentions.roles.first();
message.channel.send(`1 minute has passed <@${msg.author.id}>`)
}
});
//cd test
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   // Code goes here
}, 60000)
```

Comment: Please read the question again - this is not what the original poster is asking

Answer (score 1):

See `setTimeout()`
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${PREFIX}1cd`)) {
    //pass the code that you want to execute later as a callback function
    setTimeout(() => { 
      let user = message.mentions.roles.first();
      message.channel.send(`1 minute has passed <@${msg.author.id}>`)
    }, 60000); //60s is 60000 ms, and it takes the amount of time as milliseconds
  }
});
```